# Application Loader Error: UIRequiredDeviceCapablities incompatible with MinimumOSVersion of '3.0'

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to release an update for my app, and am running into an error when submitting the binary for review. My first release was accepted into the app store but was not compatible with older generation iPod touches. To solve this, I made sure that the minimum OS version was set to 3.0 (3.1.3 being the latest firmware those devices can update to as far as I know). The full error says: "This Bundle is invalid. The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities contains value 'armv7' which is incompatible with the MinimumOSVersion value of '3.0'. 
Here are my current build settings: [image: build settings] [image: info.plist settings]

I have seen a few other posts on stackoverflow and other websites but none of them seem to target my exact problem and the solutions have proved unsuccessful. I appreciate all of the help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support iOs 3.0 you should just change `deployment target` to **3.0** in your project settings and target settings (build settings). I've never used `MinimumOSVersion` and `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`. May be they are for MacOs apps?

Comment: No, they are definitely for iOS Development

Comment: You shouldn't set them by yourself. Check here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old, but for anyone else coming across it what you need to do is edit your -Info.plist file, changing "Required device capabilities" from "armv6" to "armv7".